# How to put off cache in JQM when returning to home page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

After page is loaded i press a link and a particular page is loaded. The problem starts when i want to go back to the index page - the page is "cached". It stays in the DOM with `display:none` or something that, but i need that it would load every time as new, how to do this? I already tried:

- `jQuery.ajaxSetup({cache: false});`
- `jQuery.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;`
- `data-cache="false"`
- `jQuery.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = false;`

Comment: Where did you place `jQuery.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;`? It needs to go belog `<script src=jquery.js>` but before `<script src=jquerymobile.js>` and must be called on `mobileinit` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is still a bit buggy, at least **data-cache="false"**.

## Solution 1

To disable cashing on a app level you need to do it in mobileinit event, like this:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = false;
});
```

one more thing, a lot of people don't understand this part. **Mobileinit** event MUST be initialized before jQuery Mobile is initialized, like this:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
        $.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = false;
    });
</script> <!-- Note your script before jqm -->
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

## Solution 2

Sometimes you don't want to disable page cashing on a app level, in this case data-cache="false" should work, unfortunately it is not working as intended. But it can be forced like this:

```
$('div').on('pagehide', function(event, ui){
  var page = $(event.target);

  if(page.attr('data-cache') == 'false'){
    page.remove();
  };
});
```

This part of code will remove page after it is hidden.

Here's a live jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/wgLzu/

Comment: thanks, also one more question - can i use `on` instead of `bind` ?